# PHP rounding function not working for rounding up

Tags: php

For the code below, sometimes the value **$endorsepoints** is not a whole number.  I want it to be rounded off, up or down, depending on normal math rules.

Then, I want to input the rounded number into two MySQL tables, **comment** and **submission**.

I want the number rounded up or down per normal math rules.

When the number is supposed to be rounded down (i. e. 5203.25), the correct rounded number (i. e. 5203.00) gets added to both **comment** and **submission**.

When the number is supposed to be rounded up (i. e. 5151.74), the correct rounded number (i. e. 5152.00) gets added to **submission**.  However, in this situation, the rounded down number (i. e. 5151.00) is added to **comment**.  How can I make the rounded up number go into **comment** in this situation?

```
   $endorsepoints = $endorsepoints * .01;

    $endorsepoints2 = ( $endorsepoints <= 10 ) ? 10 : $endorsepoints;

    $endorsepoints2 = round($endorsepoints2);





    $query1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO comment VALUES (NULL, %d, %d, '%s', %d, NULL)", $uid, $submissionid, $comment, $endorsepoints2);

    mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());


    $query2 = sprintf("UPDATE submission SET points = (points + '$endorsepoints2') WHERE submissionid = '$submissionid'");

    mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT:  I want the same number inserted into both tables at all times.  My question is: why is it not?

Comment: Why not use the 2nd and 3rd arguments to round()?

Comment: Sorry I can't get the question. As I see `$endorsepoints2` in both cases is same number?? So what do you mean by _However, in this situation, the rounded down number (i. e. 5151.00) is added to comment._

Answer (score 0):

```
$endorsepoints3 = $endorsepoints2;
$endorsepoints2 = round($endorsepoints2);

if($endorsepoints3 > $endorsepoints2) {
    //rounded down
} else {
    //rounded uo
}
```

I'm not sure if you were asking this, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the round() function will always round correctly i.e. 2.4 becomes 2 and 2.6 becomes 3, are you perhaps looking for floor() and ceil() and number_format() to round to lowest or highest, get decimals "and know about it"?

thereafter its as simple as using an if/else to run a query based on the result matching <==>

Answer (score -1):

use `ceil()` instead of `round()`

it rounds only up

Comment: I'm trying to round up or down.